# Is 5.5.56 version Mariadb dump is compatible with Mariadb 5.5.60?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, version, mariadb-connector-c

I want to take mariadb database dump (version 5.5.56) and I want to import on mariadb (5.5.60), Is it compatible? Can I import it?

Also do I need to take dump of whole databases? or just individual databases? if so, do I need to import inbuilt schema also "information_schema", "performance_schema", "mysql" ? what is advisable?

```
 mysqldump -S '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' -u root -proot --host=localhost --single-transaction --all-databases --master-data=1 > ~/hadoopMYSQL.out
```

Comment: in my experience is complety compatible,  i have restored mysql dumps in  mariadb and I didn't have to modify anything. i generally prepare my dumps by datebase.  information_schema, performance_schema, users and mysql dont have to be restored because are mysql dbs, and maria db has their own

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minor versions (5.5.xx to 5.5.yy) should always be compatible.  Major (5.5 to 5.6) *may* be compatible.  But...

Do *not* try to import `information_schema` or `performance_schema`.  `mysql` is iffy -- it may need `mysql_upgrade` to be applied if there are schema changes.  And it is very likely to be 'wrong' to import that into 8.0.